# Histogram aggregation OR something else?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

Which `aggregation` should I use, when I want same functionality as `Histogram`, BUT with specify only number of buckets, instead of specify interval?

Something like: give me `aggs` for price, and split it to 5 buckets...

I don’t want to make min+max `aggregation`, then calculate 5 intervals before sending my query, because that means 1 extra query on server ... first ask for min+max, then send actual query.

STANDARD HISTOGRAM AGGS QUERY:

```
"aggs":{
    "prices":{
        "histogram": {
            "field": "variants.priceVat.d1",
            "interval": 500
        }
    }
}
```

STANDARD RESULT (min 10, max 850 = 2 buckets, because interval is 500):

```
"prices": {
    "doc_count": 67,
    "prices": {
        "buckets": [
            {
                "key": 10,
                "doc_count": 56
            },
            {
                "key": 500,
                "doc_count": 13
            }

        ]
    }
}
```

WHAT I WANT (five buckets with automatic range min:10, max:850 = 1 bucket interval is 168):

```
"prices": {
    "doc_count": 67,
    "prices":{
        "buckets": [
            {
                "key": 10,
                "doc_count": 42
            },
            {
                "key": 178,
                "doc_count": 10
            },
            {
                "key": 346,
                "doc_count": 4
            },
            {
                "key": 514,
                "doc_count": 7
            },
            {
                "key": 682,
                "doc_count": 2
            }

        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: What you should do is to show a few sample document and illustrate what output you expect.

Comment: I added some examples

Comment: you can use pipeline aggregations, as your final aggregator need interval value which needs to be evaluated in the same context